# FreeRadius config: reject request upon inner-tunnel auth type is "none"

Tags: freeradius

I just set up an freeradius server (Version 2.2.5) on an Raspeberian PI with DaloRadius 0.99 web interface. OS = Debian Jessy. I do not use certificates for authentification.

Everythings working fine, I restricted the used authentification types to "PEAP" for 1st authentification and the inner-tunnel (second auth to MSCHAP(V2)).

Now I recognized when I configure a client using PEAP and no inner tunnel Auth method it's although possible to dial in.

I want to restrict the second auth to only accept MSCHAP/MSCHAPV2 and not "none" as auth metohd.

Comment: Use two instances of EAP, list one in the outer server, one in the inner server.  Use proxy_as_eap in the outer EAP instance.

Remove all modules except EAP in the authorize and authenticate sections of the inner tunnel.